# Material-UI 5 DataGrid styles are not isolated between components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've just upgraded from Material-UI v4 to v5 (now MUI).
If I have a `DataGrid` component and a component like a `Select` component (a `MenuItem` has issues too), the `Select` component will not work properly. Some additional styles loaded by the `DataGrid` interfere with it.

The example I'll show here is that values no longer dropdown, but are instead listed horizontally all smashed together. Note that the `DataGrid` is intentionally empty for this demo.

[image: Select dropdown not working when DataGrid exists]

As opposed to the expected functionality like this:

[image: Select dropdown working as expected]

I've put the code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datagrid-isolation-issue-xxol4)

Notice that `"@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.0"` has a dependency on `"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3"`. I was/am uncomfortable with that, but it does have it listed as a dependency (unless I missed something somewhere).

Is there something I'm missing, or is there a bug in the newest version of `DataGrid` I'm using? BTW, all of the the `DataGrid` functionality in my actual application works fine.

For completeness, I'll also include the code here:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Select>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
      {/* with DataGrid, Select will shown options on one line */}
      {/* comment out DataGrid and the select will work */}
      <DataGrid rows={[]} columns={[]} /> 
    </div>
  );
}
render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

The package.json file is:

```json
{
  "name": "mui-datagrid-isolation-issue",
  "version": "5.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "latest",
    "@emotion/styled": "latest",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NearlHuscarl! This worked. What had confused me was that when they just renamed the packaged from material-ui to mui/material, they did that for the older version too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're using v4 `@mui/x-data-grid` which uses JSS while the MUI components are in v5 which uses emotion. The JSS styles from the old version [overrides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjYMF.png) the emotion styles leading to unexpected result.

To fix it, install the next version (v5) of `@mui/x-data-grid` so it can be compatible with MUI v5, and also remove `@material-ui/core` v4 in your `package.json`.

```
npm install @mui/x-data-grid@next
```

You can always look at the [package.json](https://codesandbox.io/s/o0wsw?file=/package.json) file in the [docs](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/rows/#feeding-data) demo to see what a working project look like.

Comment: Thanks!! That finally solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer @NearHuscarl. I don't have the reputation to comment. It took me a while to figure this out as the docs at [MUI Data Grid Component demo page](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/) are still pointing to `npm install @mui/x-data-grid`, which leads to the wrong package being installed for MUI5.

Comment: The installation guide [here](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/getting-started/#installation) points to the next version now.