# MUI v5 - Select component renders menu horizontally

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the MUI v5 `TextField` component with the `Select` option.

Why is it rendering the menu horizontally?
[image]

Comment: please attach some code

Comment: This looks [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69309151/9449426), can you have a look at it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material-UI 5 DataGrid styles are not isolated between components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69309151/material-ui-5-datagrid-styles-are-not-isolated-between-components)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Select component can't shadow mui's data grid, that's why menu's not vertical as it should be

Comment: Can you attach any resource that explain how to actually solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem using MuiSelect. The problem occured when I was using MenuItem from MUI v5 - importing from MaterialUI v4 instead did the trick.