# How to change the background color of MUI Menu Popover of TextField with select property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to achieve that the popover respectively the menu of a `TextField` with 'select' property changes the background color. I followed the instructions of [MUI customization docs](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#1-one-off-customization). I had success in changing i.e. color of text and label of a `TextField` with following code.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: "azure",
    '& .MuiInputLabel-root': { color: "#adadad",}
  }
})
```

```html
const TextFieldBar = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Stack className={classes.root} >
      <TextField
        select
      >
        <MenuItem>
          Option 1
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          Option 2
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          Option 3
        </MenuItem>
      </TextField>
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

But I get stuck when trying to change anything of the popover when you click on a `Select` component. I've to mention, that it's not exactly a Select component since I'm using a `TextField` with 'select' property. So my question is, which class I should use to change the background. I inspected the html element and tried all applied classes like in the following snippet, but with no success.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiPaper-root': {background: 'black'}; //doesn't work
    '& .MuiPaper-rounded': {background: 'black'}; //doesn't work
    '& .MuiPaper-elevation': {background: 'black'}; //doesn't work
    .
    .
    .
  }
})
```

I think that I didn't understand the system behind customizing MUI components, yet. It's just a guess but maybe I can't reach the html element since the popover/menu is not a child of the Stack or TextField component on which I apply my custom styles.

I'm using

- React 17.0.2
- mui-core 5.0.0-alpha.47
- @mui/material 5.0.3
- @mui/styles 5.0.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it's not exactly a Select component since I'm using a TextField with 'select' property" - `TextField` with select is basically a `Select` [behind the scene](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/TextField/TextField.js#L204-L217).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Paper` is not inside the `Select` in the DOM tree, by default it uses [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to display the menu list, because of that, you cannot target the descending class name unless you use `MenuProps.disablePortal`. To overcome that, MUI provides the `MenuProps` so you can pass the props to the `Paper` including the `className`:

```
<TextField
  select
  label="Select"
  SelectProps={{
    MenuProps: {
      PaperProps: {
        className: classes.paper
      }
    }
  }}
```

Since you're using **v5**, you can also use the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content). Note that, the MUI team does not recommend using `makeStyles` because it's deprecated and may be removed in the future versions:

```
<TextField
  select
  label="Select"
  SelectProps={{
    MenuProps: {
      PaperProps: {
        sx: {
          backgroundColor: "pink",
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the sample on CodeSandbox. Since I was pretty sure that your code must be right and your code in my case still didn't work I searched for another reason. Long story short: It was the alpha version of MUI. After reinstalling current version of MUI it now works.

Comment: I played around with both and noticed, that first one, using `classes.paper` works on first render and after reloading the page it falls back to initial MUI style. Second one, using sx property works even after reload. Thanks for mentioning deprecation of `makeStyles`. Would you recommend using `classes` instead of `makeStyles` as well?

Comment: @marco I'm not sure what you mean by choosing between `classes` and `makeStyles`, `makeStyles`/`withStyles` are deprecated, the output of those APIs are the classnames where you can pass into the `className` or `classes` props. The new API `styled`/`sx` doesn't expose the className anymore.

Comment: @marco It probably doesn't work as expected because both v4 and v5 add the same MUI class selectors but use [different styling libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69508854/9449426) under the hood, so you should migrate the styles to v5 completely to prevent bugs like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69309151/9449426).

Answer (score 0):

Use `classes` or `emotion styled` instead of `makeStyles`

[Menu Docs](https://mui.com/api/menu/)
[MenuItem Docs](https://mui.com/api/menu-item/)

**Classes:**

```js
<MenuItem
    classes={{...}}
>
    ...
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Also use `selected` in MenuItem

Answer (score 0):

You can use global style to achive this thing

For Mui V4.

```
const darkTheme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiMenu: {
      paper: {
        background: "none !important",
        backdropFilter: "blur(10px) !important",
      },
    },
  },
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
  },
});
```

For Mui V5.

```
const darkTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiMenu: {
      styleOverrides: {
        paper: {
          background: "none !important",
          backdropFilter: "blur(10px) !important",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
  },
});
```